# In Angular, how to navigate to a relative path with `href`?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am using Ionic with Angular (i.e. and `@angular/router`), but I believe that this question is also relevant to Angular without Ionic.

How can I navigate to a relative folder using `href`?

I have this structure:

```
(root)
..A
....B1
....B2
```

When I navigate to `/A/B1` - the `B1` component is rendered. In it, I have this HTML:

```
<ios-button href="../B2">Click Me</ios-button>
```

I expect a button click to navigate to `/A/B2`, but instead, it navigates to `/B2`.

I also tried `href="./../B2"` but it gives the same result.

If I use the full path (`href="/A/B2"`) then it works.

How do I achieve my expected result with the partial (i.e. relative) path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an option to implement it like this, handling redirection inside your Component

More info on [Angular's specifying-a-relative-route](https://angular.io/guide/router#specifying-a-relative-route) documentation

```
@Component({...})
export class TestComponent {

   constructor(
      private router: Router
      private route: ActivatedRoute
   ) {}

   navigateTo(path: string): void {
       this.router.navigate([path], { relativeTo: this.route });        
   }
}
```

With this in place `{ relativeTo: this.route }` and if you have a path `../B2`, you're telling Angular that from this current route, go 1-step backward and go to `B2`

**Mock Parent Route:** http://localhost:4200/parent

Example #1

```
// This will be http://localhost:4200/parent/B2
this.router.navigate(['B2'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Example #2

```
// This will be http://localhost:4200/B2
// As this goes up one level
this.router.navigate(['../B2'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

---

**NOTE:**

- When dealing with route redirection, it's best to use `[routerLink]=""` instead of `href` inside your template

  - Accessing levels up `<a [routerLink]="[../B2]">B2</a>`
  - If one level only, `<a [routerLink]="'B2'">B2</a>` with single quote inside
- Or if you'll handle redirection in your component, you'll use `Router` from `@angular/router`

---

Have created a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-route-basic?file=src/app/b2/b2.component.ts)** for your reference

Comment: Thanks! I'm asking specifically about how to do this at the HTML side. I tried `routerLink` as you suggested, but it didn't work. When I did `<a [routerLink]="../B2">` - the page didn't load (I got an "Unexpected token ." JS error). I tried `<a [routerLink]="'../B2'">` which didn't cause an error, but also didn't work (nothing happened when I clicked on the button). I got the same result with `[routerLink]="['../B2']"` :(

Comment: Oh I see, the answer above is dependent if you have declared router paths in your angular routing like this: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5 -- May I know if you have declared the paths in this approach?

Comment: I.. believe so.. I do have an `app-routing.module` file (that was generated with `ionic start`). Though the `/B1` and `/B2` "sub routes" are managed by a "sub routing file" of the `A` module (i.e. they are in `a-routing.module.ts`). Now I'm beginning to suspect that I got something wrong with my general structure / routing, because I also encountered another problem with `(ngSubmit)` not firing event in component `B1`, but does work in component `A`. So it makes me think I have some lower-level mistake (which I don't expect to solve in the scope of this question here...)

Comment: @obe have updated the answer above, especially on the Note section, and have created a Stackblitz Demo for your reference for the sample nested route with parent and child accessing a direct route or with by level like ../B2 . Hope it helps :)

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. Your demo works (thank you!!), so I'm almost certain the problem lies elsewhere in my code. I will continue to troubleshoot, but anyway I will accept your answer here :) thanks!